# Is there a probe for shutdown or before kill pods in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

Is there a way to get a trigger to shutdown, so we can close all connections gracefully before shutdown and don't proceed any actions after that probe and keeping the probe ready to kill.

This including flushing logs, keeping any state of the application saved before handing over to the new pod and many more use cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 options:

1. Containers (PID 1) receive SIGTERM before the container (and the pod) is removed. You can trap SIGTERM and act on it.
2. You can use the [preStop lifecycle hook](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/container-lifecycle-hooks/#hook-details)

Important implementation details can be found here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod/#termination-of-pods

### httpGet example

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: prestop-pod
spec:
  terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 5
  containers:
    - name: nginx
      image: nginx
      lifecycle:
        preStop:
          httpGet:
            # only port is reqired
            port: 80
            path: "?preStop"
            # scheme: HTTP
            # host: ...
            # httpHeaders:
            #   name: ...
            #   value: ...
```

After `kubectl apply -f` on this file, run `kubectl log -f prestop-pod` while executing `kubectl delete pod prestop-pod` on another terminal. You should see something like:

```
$ kubectl apply -f prestop.yaml 
pod/prestop-pod created
$ kubectl logs -f prestop-pod
10.244.0.1 - - [21/Mar/2019:09:15:20 +0000] "GET /?preStop HTTP/1.1" 200 612 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1" "-"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please add an example for http prestop hook. I could not find example for http GET on that link.

Comment: Added example :)